# Accessing Record fields with keywords in ClojureScript not working as in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When I try this:

```clj
(defrecord Attr [has-default default])
(def attr (->Attr true 1))
(get attr :default) ;;=> 1
(:default attr) ;;=> ClojureScript returns nil, Clojure returns 1
```

Is the difference in behavior when using keyword access expected? I couldn't find anything about it in the [docs][1]  on the differences between Clojure and ClojureScript.

**Update 2020-08-04**

Deleted. See next.

**Update 2020-08-06**

It has been pointed out that my previous update contained a spelling error that caused the problem. I have removed the update rather than leave it as a trap for future readers.

It does not change the original observations or the solution.

```
  [1]: https://www.clojurescript.org/about/differences#_data_structures
```

Comment: Verified. Looks like a bug. You should send an email to `clojure@googlegroups.com`

Comment: I tested it with shadow-cljs and got the same strange behavior. You can use `:has-default` to look-up the value in `attr` but `:default` doesn't work, despite being one of the keys: https://gist.github.com/dfuenzalida/6bff139ccafee03cce0172ce82f0bee4

Comment: This has something to do with `default` sometimes getting munged to `default$` since `default` used to be a reserved JS literal. Not entirely sure under which circumstances this happens. Also the official place to report these kinds of things is now https://ask.clojure.org

Comment: @Thomas Heller: That seems to be the problem. By changing `default` to something different, like `default-val`, it works as expected everywhere I can think of to try it. Thanks.